# importing a package that doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I've never seen an import issue like this before. I removed a directory from `site-packages` and the corresponding package is still importable.

```
python2
> import google
> print(google.__path__)
['/home/bamboo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google']
```

However this directory doesn't actually exist

```
ls: cannot access /home/bamboo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google: No such file or directory
```

I've removed everything that I'm aware of that is related to it, but there must still be something hanging around.

Digging another level deeper I tried to reload `google`.

```
python2
> import google;
> reload(google);
ImportError: No module named google
```

So apparently it recognizes it is gone on reload.

Checking out `sys.modules` you get

```
python2
> import sys
> print(sys.modules)
{'google': <module 'google' (built-in)>, 'copy_reg': <module 'copy_reg' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc'> ...
```

which indicates that apparently `google` is a built-in.

**Note on motivation:** Usually this sort of issue would be weird, but not a show stopper. The problem for me is that the `google` package is masking a different package of the same name.

Comment: If you're hanging on to a Python session that was running before you deleted this directory, restart Python.

Comment: @user2357112 is there a way that could happen without knowing about it? So far as I can tell I am starting a fresh session each time.

Comment: If you're in an IDE or something, you could still be using the same Python interpreter. The sessions you're posting don't look like any Python environment I'm familiar with.

Comment: They are in Bambo unfortunately, tossed into a build command to try to figure out what is happening. So, `echo "import sys; print(sys.modules);" | python2;` as an example.

Comment: Best guess:  it's an artifact of the Bamboo environment.  It's not common for build tools / containers (e.g. Docker) / cloud platforms to provide a modified Python environment.

Comment: any stray ***.pyc** hanging around in sys.path?  doesn't fit your case that well but many times bitten on deletion of my python scripts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl,dr:** use `pip` to uninstall Google packages completely.

There are two issues here:

- strange import/reload behaviour of the google package
- removal of the google package

#### import/reload behavior

I can reproduce the import/reload behaviour by installing the (Google) [protobuf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf/3.5.1) package (many Google packages will behave in the same way).

```
$ mktmpenv -p $(which python2)
...
$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
$ pip install protobuf
...
Installing collected packages: six, protobuf
Successfully installed protobuf-3.5.1 six-1.11.0

>>> import google
>>> print google.__path__
['~/virtual-envs/tmp-66cd9b4d01a8dec6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google']
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.modules['google']
<module 'google' (built-in)>
>>> reload(google)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named google
```

I suspect what's going on here is that Google prefer to have all Google packages installed under a single `google` package, but this package is not designed to be importable, hence the unexpected reload behaviour.  However importing subpackages by name works as expected:

```
>>> import protobuf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named protobuf

>>> from google import protobuf
>>> protobuf.__path__
['~/virtual-envs/tmp-66cd9b4d01a8dec6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf']
>>> reload(protobuf)
<module 'google.protobuf' from '~/virtual-envs/tmp-66cd9b4d01a8dec6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

#### Removal of the google package

The question states:

> I removed a directory from site-packages and the corresponding package is still importable.

This can also be reproduced:

```
($ rm -rf ~/virtual-envs/tmp-66cd9b4d01a8dec6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google
$  python
>>> import google
>>> print google.__path__
['~/virtual-envs/tmp-66cd9b4d01a8dec6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google']
>>>
```

The problem here is that simply removing the `google` directory and its contents is not enough to completely uninstall whatever Google packages are present.

The site-packages directory still contains the file `protobuf-3.5.1-py2.7-nspkg.pth`, which contains this code (split into separate lines for readability, the original is a single line of semi-colon separated statements):

```
import sys, types, os
has_mfs = sys.version_info > (3, 5)
p = os.path.join(sys._getframe(1).f_locals['sitedir'], *('google',))
importlib = has_mfs and __import__('importlib.util')
has_mfs and __import__('importlib.machinery')
m = has_mfs and sys.modules.setdefault('google', importlib.util.module_from_spec(importlib.machinery.PathFinder.find_spec('google', [os.path.dirname(p)])))
m = m or sys.modules.setdefault('google', types.ModuleType('google'))
mp = (m or []) and m.__dict__.setdefault('__path__',[])
(p not in mp) and mp.append(p)
```

The line

`m = m or sys.modules.setdefault('google', types.ModuleType('google'))`

is creating the `google` module in `sys.modules` if it doesn't already exist - this is why the `google` module is importable even after the directory has been deleted.

The correct way to remove the `google` module is by uninstalling google packages using `pip`:

`pip uninstall protobuf`

If `pip` isn't available in the build environment the it's a case of identifying any related files and folders (`*dist-info/`, `*.pth`) in site-packages and removing them manually.

Comment: Ah, it's a(n old-style) namespace package, not the [janky thing on PyPI under the name "google"](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google). That makes sense.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I suppose it is - there's no `__init__.py` in the google folder.  I'll try to read up on them and improve the answer's technical accuracy.