# gmail API : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api

While running the quickstart.py of Gmail, I get the following error on macOS.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 4, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
  File "/Users/<user>/Documents/venv/bin/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 49, in <module>
    import google.api_core.client_options
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

These are the installed Google libraries.

```
$ pip freeze | grep google
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
google-api-core==1.16.0
google-api-python-client==1.8.0
google-auth==1.12.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-cloud-bigquery==1.24.0
google-cloud-core==1.3.0
google-resumable-media==0.5.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.51.0
```

Comment: If you `pip install google`, then uninstall it. The google library on PyPI is not owned by Google. I think what you're looking for is `pip install googleapiclient` (or google-api-client, I can't recall)

Comment: [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48108908/5320906)

Answer (score 1):

From the error, the google module is not installed for Python3.
I'm gonna take a wild guess and say it's because your version of Python(Python2.7) has depreciated, clearly, try using python3.7(alongside pip3) hopefully it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should run

```
 pip install google-cloud
```

If the issue persist then you have some issues with you python paths.

You should check where the google package actually is installed:

```
 python3 -c 'import google; print(google.__file__)'
```

Also you can try to install your packages in a virtualenv:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
venv/bin/pip install your-packages
venv/bin/python -c 'import google'
deactivate
rm -fr venv/
```

Comment: I install the google-cloud package and import also works but `import google; print(google.__file__)` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The library `google-api-core 1.16.0` is no longer supported in Python 2.7. Only versions above 3.5 are supported, as specified [here](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-core/):

> **Supported Python Versions**: Python >= 3.5
>
> **Deprecated Python Versions**: Python == 2.7. Python 2.7 support will be removed on January 1, 2020.

You should upgrade to a supported Python version.

#### Reference:

- [google-api-core 1.16.0](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-core/)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are using `python3` rather than `python2.7`. Using `pip` is pointing to your `python2.7` installation. You can use `pip` for python3 by slightly editing the command you are running in your shell:

```sh
pip3 install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Even more secure could be this (do note that we use pip, not pip3 in this command):

```sh
python3 -m pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

This command will point to the `python3` interpreter you are currently using.

Also make sure your `venv` is activated when using the above commands if you want to work in your virtual environment.